# SqlCommand result - Object cannot be cast from dbnull to other types

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have got this `SqlCommand` that `Sum all payments for client`, but the issue is where there are no payments the result is null or 0 - I'm not sure. But I still receive the same exception: Object cannot be cast from dbnull to other types

What Exception or if statement can fix it?

```
 private void select_payments()
    {

        try
        {

            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(payment) AS sumpayment FROM clientpayments WHERE subkey='" + selectid + "' AND year='" + selectedyear+ "'", con);

            con.Open();
            int result = Convert.ToInt32(sc.ExecuteScalar());
            con.Close();

            if (result != 0)
            {
                Convert.ToDecimal(textBox20.Text = result .ToString().Replace(',', '.'));
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" " + ex.Message.ToString());

        }
    }
```

I'm still receiving this exception:

> object cannot be cast from dbnull to other types

I know that this is low-quality question but I'm not sure how can I fix this.

Thank you for your time and answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options.  Fix your SQL Statement, or your Convert.

SQL - Wrap your `SUM` in an `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(payment), 0)
```

Convert - Compare it to `DBNull.Value` first:

```
var result = sc.ExecuteScalar();
int intResult = result == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(result);
```

Comment: Perhaps SELECT SUM(ISNULL(payment,0))... Payment probably should allow NULL in the definition any way.

Answer (score 2):

```
object o = sc.ExecuteScalar();
con.Close();
if (o != null)
{
  int result = (int) o;
  if(result != 0)  Convert.ToDecimal(textBox20.Text = result .ToString().Replace(',', '.'));
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't o = `DBNull.Value` and not null.  Therefore resulting in the same error?

Comment: @JefferyKhan no error here if the result set is empty, the `null` is returned. The MSDN page says **`Return value: The first column of the first row in the result set, or a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the result set is empty...`**