# need to handle NULL exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, null

```
private int MyTimeValue()
{
    int Value = 0;
    string connectionString = GetConfigurationSettingValue("ConnectionString");
    int Days = 120;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select [dbo].[My_function] (@Span)", connection))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Span", Days));

            Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        }
    }

    return (Value);
}
```

I'm getting `Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.`

How can i handle null exception here using `try` and `catch`

please help me for syntax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SqlCommand result - Object cannot be cast from dbnull to other types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359571/sqlcommand-result-object-cannot-be-cast-from-dbnull-to-other-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in 2 ways.

Case 1: Handling Specific Exception

```
private int MyTimeValue()
{
    int Value = 0;
    try
    {      
       string connectionString = GetConfigurationSettingValue("ConnectionString");
       int Days = 120;

       using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
       {
           connection.Open();
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select [dbo].[My_function] (@Span)", connection))
           {
               cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Span", Days));

               Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

           }
       }
     catch(NullReferenceException ex)
     {
        \\Handle Exception
     }

     return (Value);

}
```

Case 2: Check variables for Null and also Catch General Exception for other unexpected exceptions

```
    private int MyTimeValue()
{
    int Value = 0;
    try
    {      
       string connectionString = GetConfigurationSettingValue("ConnectionString");
       int Days = 120;

       using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
       {
           connection.Open();
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select [dbo].[My_function] (@Span)", connection))
           {
               cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Span", Days));
               var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
               if(result !=null)
                    Value = Convert.ToInt32(result );

           }
       }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
        \\For handling unexpected exceptions
     }   
     return (Value);
}
```

Comment: IS this a best approach  ?  IF `NULL` will this return a `0`

Comment: @ashuthinks no, it is not the best approach because it is not exceptional situation (i.e. you expect that sometimes value will be null) and it is a bad idea to handle all exception types and make large `try` block too.

Comment: You should not be depending upon general Exception. Rather you should handle specific Exception. And better if you validate variables before using especially if they are coming from outside you function.

Comment: Yes. I just updated question. You can you any of the above case. If its the to your question, you can accept that answer. :)

Comment: `if(DBNull.Value!=null)` what ? :p

Comment: correct `Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())` as well

Answer (score 3):

you can validate before convert

```
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if(result != null)
    Value = Convert.ToInt32(result);
```

and also add the parameter as below

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Span", Days);
```

as side note, line `cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;` is no need. default command type is Text

Answer (score 2):

I guess the error is here:

```
Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Try this:

```
var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
Value = result == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(result);
```

Note: Also your command string seems wrong to me.

Comment: This calls ExecuteScalar() twice.

Comment: @Selman22 have you edited your ans? which one is best approach to do ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the value return by the ExecuteScalar is null or not first, so that the exception wont occur while trying to cast the object to Int32.

```
private int MyTimeValue()
    {
        int Value = 0;
        string connectionString = GetConfigurationSettingValue("ConnectionString");
        int Days = 120;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select [dbo].[My_function] (@Span)", connection))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Span", Days));
                object o=cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if(o!=null)
                   Value = Convert.ToInt32(o);

            }
        }

        return (Value);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
          Value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();    
          if (((Value != null) || (Value != DBNull.Value)))
          {
          Value =(int)Value ;
          }
```